# Check whether running on server or locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I have a website with game client and a server running next to the website. They communicate via sockets. The problem is that I need to have a way of setting url 
 for my socket depending whether the code is on server or on my local pc. When I want to debug my code and write development code I want the url to be `localhost:5051` and when I push it to the server I want it to be the name of the website with specific port.

Is there any way of determining whether my code is on production or development?
I don't use `webpack`, I only use `requirejs` and I would like it to stay that way, because I need to change only one line and I don't want to use the whole framework to change one line.

Comment: Take url from, params file and change that variable in params file according to environment

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your Node file is server.js and you typically start your app by typing `node server.js`. When you run your app locally, instead use:

```
NODE_ENV='development' node server.js
```

Now in your app, set a var for your url.

```
var appUrl = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') ? 'localhost:5051' : 'your-prod-url.com';
```

Use `appUrl` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to determine which environment you're on by logging socket.localAddress and .localPort, where socket is your socket's name, and setting the URL accordingly.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_localaddress